# Creating a staging table when the target table has autoincrement

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is it possible to create a staging table when the target table has an autoincrement ID key, and then merge it back in?

I've attempted this:

```
 CREATE  TEMP TABLE stage (like target);


insert
into
    stage
    (colA, colB, colC)
```

Where the `target` table has an autoincrement column `id`.  When I run this script, I get back the following error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Cannot insert a NULL value into column id
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Cannot insert a NULL value into column id
  code:      8007
  context:   query execution
  query:     896442
  location:  column:1
  process:   query1_51 [pid=15458]
  -----------------------------------------------;
```

Comment: can you drop the ID column from staging table after creating it and then insert?

Comment: please share the ddl code you used to create the table?

Comment: @JonScott I posted an answer to what I did on the DBA page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the same question I asked at [DBA.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/189972/18520)(which was also a self answer)

> What I ended up doing was creating a staging table without using LIKE
>   TARGET, from there I created a few queries to see what values were in
>   the staging table vs the target table. I then inserted those values
>   into the target table, and dropped the staging table.